# How does "Cut the Rope" do such realistic animation?

Tags: animation

*"Cut the Rope"* is so smooth and real life like, while some apps are very "bitmap" like.  How does *"Cut the Rope"* do such realistic animation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

vectors are used in cut the rope. and the other games may be using bitmaps instead... like old school zelda.

Vectors you can have curve lines and such, where bitmaps are all squares.
[Vectors vs bitmaps](http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/aboutgraphics/a/bitmapvector.htm)

Comment: do you know what framework Cut the Rope uses?  Such as cocos2D or Box2D?

Comment: @動靜能量 Cut the Rope has been developed for many different platforms (Xbox kinect, HTML5, mobile) so I am not entirely sure which framework they use for each case. But if the game can be made in HTML5 it can most likely be made in most frameworks